# cannot create a Parse.File without valid data URI's or base64 encoded data

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, parse-platform, capacitor

I get following error while uploading my profile img:

> cannot create a parse file without valid data URL or base64 encoded
> data

It only happens after uploading a few times, mostly around the third time.

It happens when `new Parse.File(fileName, { base64 })` is called.

Is there something i am doing wrong, how can i work around this?

```
public async takePicture() {
    this.photo = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 100,
      width: 256,
      allowEditing: false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
    })
    return { ...this.photo }
  }

public async uploadPicture() {
    if (this.photo) {
      const base64 = this.photo.base64String

      // Save photo to backend
      const fileName = this.accountService.getUserFirstName() + Date.now() + ".jpg"

      try {
        const parseFile = new Parse.File(fileName, { base64 })
        const response = await parseFile.save()
        await this.accountService.setProfilePicture(response)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        alert(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The fix was recently released in the alpha version of the Parse JS SDK and you are not giving any details about the versions of Parse JS SDK and Parse Server you are using. https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/pull/1543

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using 3.4.3. Anyway, thanks for informing me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed, but currently only released as version [3.5.0-alpha.2](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/pull/1543). You are using an old version `3.4.3`, so the issue still occurs.

You can fork Parse Server and use the fixed alpha version of the Parse JS SDK to make it work, or wait until the release of Parse Server with the fixed version.